# Only get WiFi 4 on new router but WiFi 5 on BT hub

Tags: wireless-networking

I just picked up a new router (UniFi Dream Machine) to sit between my BT Hub and my devices, but on one computer I see slower speeds on the UDM and can see that it is on WiFi 4 802.11n and 2.4 GHz where with the BT Hub I had no problem getting Wi-Fi 5 802.11ac and 5 GHz. I've connected to the 5 GHz fine with other devices.

What can I check to get the same from the UDM on this computer?

Here are the WiFi properties from Windows 10:

UDM:

```
SSID:   EC2B
Protocol:   Wi-Fi 4 (802.11n)
Security type:  WPA2-Personal
Network band:   2.4 GHz
Network channel:    6
Link speed (Receive/Transmit):  192/117 (Mbps)
Link-local IPv6 address:    fe80::45af:6dfd:181a:e29a%11
IPv4 address:   192.168.10.84
IPv4 DNS servers:   192.168.10.1
Manufacturer:   ASUS
Description:    ASUS PCE-AC56 802.11ac Network Adapter
Driver version: 7.35.317.0
```

BT Hub:

```
SSID:   EC2B_old
Protocol:   Wi-Fi 5 (802.11ac)
Security type:  WPA2-Personal
Network band:   5 GHz
Network channel:    36
Link speed (Receive/Transmit):  192/866 (Mbps)
Link-local IPv6 address:    fe80::45af:6dfd:181a:e29a%11
IPv4 address:   192.168.1.92
IPv4 DNS servers:   192.168.1.254
Manufacturer:   ASUS
Description:    ASUS PCE-AC56 802.11ac Network Adapter
Driver version: 7.35.317.0
```

Comment: It appears you have only enabled the 2.4 GHz SSID on your UniFi device.  I would check the manual on how to activate both the 2.4 GHz SSID and the 5.0 GHz SSID (I assume the UniFi device supports both since no model numbers were provided).

Comment: It's set to both and I've connected to it fine with another device.

Comment: Is there perhaps interference between the devices, so that they drop to a slower speed? The 5 Ghz is faster, but the 2.4 GHz is longer-distance and better on traversing walls.

Comment: Did you install and configure the Ubiquiti controller software?  The documentation says "Dual-band Wave 2 access point (802.11ac, 4x4)"  I think you need the controller software to configure it (I use that software for my Ubiquiti AP).

Comment: Yeah the controller is preinstalled and I don’t think it’s interference as my phone is fine with it in the same room, it’s something specific to the network adaptor I have on this pc. I’m going to have a play with the network channel later as it was a lot higher than the 36 the BT Hub has when I connected with another pc, 150 something I think so maybe a lower one will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I connected to the UDM from another device I noticed that the network channel was set to 161. I changed it to 36 to match the BT Hub and now the affected computer can connect, so the ASUS PCE-AC56 adaptor must have some limitation on the channels it supports.